# Convert an object with key values to an array of objects with said key name and values

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

I'm getting my head stuck in a twist with this one...

I'm trying to convert my req.query I get in Express which is an object to make an array of objects so I can pass these through to SQL Server as inputs for stored procedures.

This is the data I have -

```
{ param1: 'testing123', param2: 'poooool', param300: 'nnnvncn' }
```

I want it to appear like

```
[{param1: 'testing123'},{param2: 'poooool'},{param300: 'nnnvncn'}]
```

Any idea how I would get to the desired array above?

EDIT: This is the code I went for in the end running in node.js

```
app.get('/:client/storedproc/:sp', function(req, resp){
    var sp = req.params.sp;
    var obj = req.query;
    var test = function(){ return Object.keys(obj).map(k => ({ [k]: obj[k] }));}
    var arr = test();
    console.log(arr)
});
```

Comment: Re your edit: I would double check this actually works. I'm not sure if Node natively supports all the fancy ES2015 stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for this. Given the object from your first snippet `o`:

```
return Object.keys(o).map(function(k) {
    var x = {};
    x[k] = o[k];
    return x;
});
```

Just for fun, here's how terse it is with ES2015:

```
return Object.keys(o).map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] }));
```

Comment: Damn that ES2015 is beautiful - I need to start learning so much more JS :) Thanks Asad - I will update my post above with what I went for in the end.

Comment: @Adam91Holt And that actually works in Node JS without a transpiler?

Comment: @Adam91Holt Btw, you don't need to create a separate `test` function there since you're closing over `o` anyway. Just do `var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(k => ({ [k]: obj[k] }));`